# In a PEG, process the input twice

Tags: javascript, parsing, recursion, grammar, peg

### Background

I'm using [PEG.js online](http://pegjs.org/online).

I have a [PEG](http://pastebin.com/5Fk9g2LU) that takes a function (only math assignments and expressions are valid) and returns a literal math expression equivalent, like `3+2*5`.

Example input (function):

```
main()
{
    a = 1
    b = a
    return a+b
}
```

Example output (expression): `(1)+((1))`

---

### Specifics

To ***'de-abstract' each variable***:

**First** we read each statement, and we do a *hash assignment* for each *assignment statement*.

Example resulting hash:

```
{
    a => 1
    b => a
}
```

**Then** we take the returned expression and iteratively substitute any tokens that are *valid keys* by their *value*. Do as many iterations as assignment statements there were (in this case, 2).

- Example return expression: `a+b`
- After iteration 1: `(1)+(a)`
- After iteration 2: `(1)+((1))` which is the **final output**.

---

### Problem

I used to just take that output and call `eval()` on it, to get the final value.
*But* this is an assignment (to build a PEG parser), and the teacher frowned upon "outsourcing" the parsing of the math expression itself.

I have another (much simpler) [PEG](http://pastebin.com/Y4tVmkqz) that takes a math expression and calculates its value. 
Possible options that I want to avoid:

- I *could* pipeline the output of the first PEG into the second.
- I *could* reduce the scope of my PEG and say it only calculates the raw, literal math expression (and not its value as well).

So, **the problem** is that I want to do *both steps* in the *same grammar*, but I don't know how.

I *have* to take a previous 'dive' to de-abstract the variables into literal numbers.

- If I can calculate the math at the same time that I'm substituting the variables-- how?
- If not-- how can I, once I have 'dived' into the grammar parsing, take a different path?

Comment: if your language has only assignments and expressions, you could use a global symbol table to store the value of each identifier during parsing so you can calculate the value of each expression on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Although I think that's what I was already doing... (symbol table being a hash in my case). The question was asking how to parse the resulting `2+3*5` in the *same* grammar. Maybe my desired approach was fundamentally wrong? Regardless, I have no pressing need for a reply anymore, since it turns out my teacher had misunderstood the complexity of the original grammar and has now accepted the project. This question will remain open in case anyone wants to take a shot at giving an answer.